# Why do pcb in battery reduce the input voltage that goes to the single cell li ion battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, pcb, current, nickel

And...
Why do li ion battery cut when charged directly with 5v and 1amp

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand, but lithium batteries must not be connected directly to a 5V 1A source, so do not do it or you might damage the battery and it may burn/explode. Lithium batteries need to be charged with specific current limit and specific voltage limit, 5V is too much.

Comment: To help understand, search Youtube for "overcharge lithium battery", you will find some helpful videos.

Answer (score 1):

The small PCB in some lithium ion cells is a battery protection circuit.

LiIon cells should not be charged to 5V.  It will damage them, and they may even catch fire.  The maximum a cell should be charged to is about 4.2V.

The protection curcuit will usually also switch the cell off when it is nearly flat.  This also protects the cell from damage.